# Asp.net mvc 4 bundling not returning anything

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to get my css files bundling with the new MVC4 bundling.

I've added this to my `_Layout.cshtml`:

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

When my page renders I see the style being loaded, but nothing is in the request: http://localhost/Content/css

In `Global.asax`, I've enabled:

```
BundleTable.Bundles.EnableDefaultBundles();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had an error in my page which was causing this not to work. A partial view was getting called from jQuery and returned a 500 error. Fixing that resolved this problem, now all works well.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of EnableDefaultBundles, have you tried this?

```
BundleTable.Bundles.RegisterTemplateBundles();
```

Also, I don't think you're supposed to use @Url.Content. I have this and it works:

```
<link href="@System.Web.Optimization.BundleTable.Bundles.ResolveBundleUrl("~/Content/css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```